# Show a user exists command

Tags: users, group, accounts

Is there a command that shows a user exists and is assigned to a group?

I have just used the command `usermod -a -G [GROUP] [NAME OF USER]` and assigned a user to a group but, I was wondering if there was a command which lists the users and which group they was assigned to?

If I input `cd ..` and go to `[user@user HOME] $`then once here input the command `ls` this command lists the users I have created but not what group name they're assigned to.

Comment: You shouldn't ask slightly different questions in the title the message  body. "Show a user exists" and "list users" are different requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groups` command does exactly what you are looking for. By doing `groups <username>`, it lists the groups a user is a part of. And, if the user does not exist, it will output an error saying so.

This is just if you want to list all the groups the user is a part of. If you want more information about the user and his/her groups, the `id` command also includes the ID for each group the user is a part of.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` command will come in useful here.

```
peteches@bhiyaki:~
% id peteches
uid=1000(peteches) gid=1000(peteches) groups=1000(peteches),10(wheel),135(mock)
```

Shows that the user peteches is in the groups peteches, wheel and mock

One other thing to bear in mind with `usermod` is that if you add a user to a group then any active sessions will not be updated with the new group.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the question *I was wondering if there was a command which lists the users and which group they was assigned to?*, here is one way :

```
for i in $(getent passwd|awk -F: '{print $1}'); do groups $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a command which shows if a user exists and what group they're assigned to use the command `id [USERNAME]`.

Just remember when assigning a user to a group using the command `usermod -a -G [GROUP] [NAME OF USER]` it will not go through to the next command line if the user doesn't exist. The error message the user will receive is "User '???' does not exist"

Answer (score -1):

A simple `less /etc/group` shows you the groups on your machine and the users within those groups. If you're interested in viewing primary group information they're stored in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: I guess you mean `cat` vs `ls` but anyway, this won't show user's primary group and would miss centralized group maps (e.g. nis, ldap)

Comment: Ha, I meant to say `less`, I also updated the question, I don't think he mentioned anything about primary groups but the `/etc/passwd` contains all information about primary groups.

Comment: The issue with looking `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files is that you'll miss users and groups coming from NIS, LDAP, AD and other remote naming services. You should run commands that leverage `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: thanks for explaining why my answer is bad, I didn't know that.

Comment: De nada, by the way the downvote isn't mine.